# Django: Refer to previous item in model.save() method fails

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to implement a waiting room for items with queue verification.
The general idea is to put item to waiting room if, calculate it's counter (value defining how many new items are needed to confirm this one), decrease it after adding every new item and finally confirm it after decreasing counter below zero. If there're already items in waiting room, the calculated counter is increased by the counter of previous item so items are in queue.
My implementation is very simple, but I found this solution quite fast. 
But referring to previous item is not working for me and I can't find the reason - it often returns 'random' (or at least not last one) value from Waiting objects.

Here's vital code snippet:

```
class Waiting(models.Model):                                                       
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)                                             
    counter = models.FloatField(default=0)                                         
    (...)
    def clearup(self): 
        (...) #here is decrementing and confirming part - it's working fine
    def save(self, update=False):
        if update:                                                                 
            return super(Waiting, self).save()                                     

        item = self.item                                                       
        self.clearup()
        (...) #nothing important
        self.counter = item.quantity * items_list[item.name][1]
        last = Waiting.objects.exclude(                                        
                item__name="Something I don't want here").order_by('-pk')
        if last:
            last = last[0]
            weight = items_list[last.item.name][1]
            self.counter += (last.item.quantity * weight)                       

        super(Waiting, self).save()
```

Edit: I'm retarded.

Comment: What is the query for last object in django_debug_toolbar or in console `print last.query`?

Comment: @sneawo:

    `SELECT 'app_waiting'.'id', 'app_waiting'.'item_id', 'app_waiting'.'counter' FROM 'app_waiting' INNER JOIN 'app_item' ON ('app_waiting'.'item_id' = 'app_item'.'id') WHERE NOT ('app_item'.'name' = Something I don't want here ) ORDER BY 'app_waiting'.'id' DESC`

Comment: What's doubt you that it is not returning the latest object? Query is fine as I see.

Comment: @AamirAdnan: this is example of adding items with different quality and weight:
1.25 2.00 3.00 1.40 1.40 1.05 108.00 124.00 660.00 672.00 12.25 0.30 0.25 1.00

You can see here that after 672 next value should be at least a bit higher that 672, but it's counted from zero... And actually every item should have bigger counter that previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like almost always - it was my fault. 
I implemented vital part from another approach to this problem and this caused this issues.

Thanks for trying to help me anyway.